# Asterisk Creating Script that Emails based on where call originated

Tags: bash

I'm attempting to create a script when emergency calls are placed.  Depending on what building the call is placed in will decide who receives an email notification that an emergency call was placed.  Through a little online research I've found a script that works to send the email, but as soon as I start adding conditional statements, they don't seem to work.  Below is an example of what I've tried, basically if the user's extension is between 100 and 1000 do option one if greater than 1000 do option two.  I would prefer it to be based on outbound CID, but I could not find a variable reference for that.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash
#This script emails the recorded call right after the call is hung up. Below are    the variables passed through asterisk
# $1 - year
# $2 - month
# $3 - day
# $4 - Time String
# $5 - Source
# $6 - File
# $7 - Destination
# $dt - Date and Time

dt=$(date '+%m/%d/%Y %r');


echo -e "You have a new call recording to listen to \n\n
 The call date and time was $dt \n\n
 The call was from $5 \n\n
 The call was to $7 \n\n

 if ["$5" -gt "100" -a "$5" -lt "1000"]
 then

 Please see the attached file \n\n" | mail -a /var/spool/asterisk/monitor/$1/$2/$3/$6 -s "New Call Recording" email1@domain.com

 elif ["$5" -ge "1000"]
 then

 Please see the attached file \n\n" | mail -a /var/spool/asterisk/monitor/$1/$2/$3/$6 -s "New Call Recording" email2@domain.com

 fi
```

Comment: Please ensure your tags relate to the question; this is a question about a bash script, [asterisk] is incidental to the question, at best, and your other tags had nothing at all to do with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a shambles. You've got an unterminated strings all over the place, your spacing is incorrect around your square brackets, and you're quoting numbers as strings.

Since you're using `/bin/bash` you can use Bash conditionals. As well, variable interpolation is better done with `printf` instead of embedding variables in strings. Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#This script emails the recorded call right after the call is hung up. Below are    the variables passed through asterisk
# $1 - year
# $2 - month
# $3 - day
# $4 - Time String
# $5 - Source
# $6 - File
# $7 - Destination
# $dt - Date and Time

dt=$(date '+%m/%d/%Y %r');

printf 'You have a new call recording to listen to \n\n The call date and time was %s \n\n The call was from %s \n\n The call was to %s \n\n' "$dt" "$5" "$7"

 if [[ $5 -gt 100 ]] && [[ $5 -lt 1000 ]]; then

     printf 'Please see the attached file \n\n' | mail -a "/var/spool/asterisk/monitor/$1/$2/$3/$6" -s "New Call Recording" "email1@domain.com"

 elif [[ $5 -ge 1000 ]]; then

     printf 'Please see the attached file \n\n' | mail -a "/var/spool/asterisk/monitor/$1/$2/$3/$6" -s "New Call Recording" "email2@domain.com"

 fi
```

And if you're calling this script from your dialplan, why not just include the CID as another parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You can get outbound CID for freepbx following way:

```
/usr/sbin/asterisk -rx 'database show AMPUSER/5555/outboundcid'
```

Where 5555 is CID.

Other option is lookup in db in extensions table.